# generate multiple sequences of -n:n

Tags: matlab, vectorization, seq

My Matlab is a bit rusty, and I can't come up with a neat solution (efficient),

Desired output for a given nMax:

```
nMax = 3;
mn = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(n) [(-n:n) ;(-n:n)*0+n], 1:nMax, 'UniformOutput', false));
mn =

-1     0     1    -2    -1     0     1     2    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3
 1     1     1     2     2     2     2     2     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
```

(or, ideally, its transpose).

---

*Edit:* here's a summary of the nice speedup with the proposed solution,

```
tN = [5:100, 200:50:1000];
for ii=1:length(tN)
f1 = @() f_mn(tN(ii));
f2 = @() f_mn2(tN(ii));
gain(ii) = timeit(f1)/timeit(f2);
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
nMax = 3;
u = nMax^2+2*nMax;
mn = [ ones(u, 1) zeros(u, 1) ];
vv = 1:nMax;
ww = vv.^2;
mn(ww, 1) = -2*vv+1;
mn(ww, 2) = 1;
mn = cumsum(mn, 1);
```

Not sure how efficient it will be. But it was fun writing :-)